# Adding aliased hyperlinks to Google Forms multiple choice

Tags: google-forms, links

I've a Google Form which includes a multiple choice list with radio buttons and would like each item to be a hyperlink to an item description.

Is it possible? How?

If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Google Forms will not accept aliased links.** This is set by default by Google as a security measure.

You can either add the links/hyperlinks in the section title description like:

> Option 1: google.com
> Option 2: wikipedia.org
> Option 3: bit.ly/30RKdJ9

OR

Add the links directly as choices

[image]

***You can also use a URL shortener***

Comment: Unfortunately these links are not aliased.

Comment: **Google Forms will not accept aliased links**. This is set by default by Google as a security measure. The closest you can get is using a customized URL shortener like `bit.ly/myhoice`

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.